# when kubelet has been restarted, the node status always be Ready,SchedulingDisabled

Tags: kubernetes

In my k8s cluster, if I restart kubelet.service through `systectl restart kubelet`. The node status always become `Ready,SchedulingDisabled`.

```
[cloudadmin@controller-2 ~]$ kubectl get node
NAME            STATUS                     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
192.168.90.26   Ready                      master   69d   v1.16.2
192.168.90.27   Ready                      worker   69d   v1.16.2
192.168.90.28   Ready                      worker   69d   v1.16.2
192.168.90.29   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   master   69d   v1.16.2
192.168.90.30   Ready                      master   69d   v1.16.2
```

And I need execute `kubectl uncordon <node-name>` to fix it. But it is normal in other env with restart kubelet service. So, I wonder is there any configuration I need to modify?

Comment: Can you share more info about your setup? What cloud provider are you running your cluster in? What OS is used? Can you share output of `kubectl describe node`?

Comment: here is event info about node

Comment: `kubelet, 192.168.90.26  Node 192.168.90.26 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
kubelet, 192.168.90.26  Node 192.168.90.26 status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
kubelet, 192.168.90.26  Node 192.168.90.26 status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
kubelet, 192.168.90.26  Node 192.168.90.26 status is now: NodeNotReady
kubelet, 192.168.90.26  Node 192.168.90.26 status is now: NodeNotSchedulable
kubelet, 192.168.90.26  Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods`

Comment: I just do not clear why node become `NodeNotSchedulable`.

Comment: Please post it in a question and post full output of this command.